# Reshape np.array(n, m) to np.array(m, n)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have an array like this

```
ar = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I want to get

```
array([[0., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
```

If I do as below I get

```
ar.reshape(8,2)
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

My decision is

```
npar = np.zeros((np.asarray(ar).shape[1],np.asarray(ar).shape[0]))
npar[:, 0] = ar[0]
npar[:, 1] = ar[1]
npar
array([[0., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
```

But is there more fast & convinient way?

Comment: how about simply taking the transpose? ```arr.T```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to take the transpose I think

```
np.transpose(ar)
```